# How do you find system manufacturer/model on Linux without root access?

Tags: linux, hardware

I'm working on a module for [Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor) that will collect hardware information so that we can use realistic numbers to compute power savings, etc.  The difficulty is that I don't maintain most of the client systems, so I have to write this with no assumptions as to what may or may not be installed on the system and I can't do anything that requires root access.

I've looked at various utilities (lshal, lshw, hwinfo, etc) and none of them seem to be universal across both Debian- and RedHat-based systems.  I have neither the authority nor the desire to force other departments on campus to have one of those packages installed.

dmidecode seems to be pretty universal, but it's not helpful without root privileges.  I haven't been able to find any files in /proc that contain the system manufacturer and model.  Is there something I'm missing or do I need to try to get all of the distributed admins to install one of the aforementioned utilities?

Answer (score 3):

You're going to need dmidecode to get that info-and even that isn't going to guarantee you can get the correct hardware info. It should work for Dell and HP server machines, but everything outside of their gets kind of dicey.

Comment: I've found DMIdecode works pretty well on any server/workstation grade hardware. The ulta-cheap consumer grade equipment, not so much. DMIDecode also runs on BSD systems and a variety of other *nix (YMMV).

Comment: dmidecode is a great tool, but entirely unhelpful for me in this case, since the Condor process does not run as root.  The only way it would work is if I got the administrators of the machines this will run on to make dmidecode setuid, which sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: Then you're up a creek. You're going to need something to decode the data stored in the BIOS and you need to be running as root to get to that data. The other option is to allow them to set the make/model in your app so you can make some guesses as to the amount of power its using.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit second-hand, but you might try running 'dmesg' and seeing if anything interesting is there.  Doesn't (usually) require root privs.

Answer (score 0):

The files you are looking for are in `/sys`, not `/proc`.  Take a look at what's available in the directory `/sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id`.  For example:

```
$ cd /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id
$ cat sys_vendor product_name product_version
System76
Pangolin
pang11
$ ls -l product_*
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 24 00:09 product_family
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May  9 15:38 product_name
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 May 24 00:09 product_serial
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May 24 00:09 product_sku
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 May  9 15:38 product_uuid
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 May  9 15:38 product_version
```

As the file permissions show, you need to be root to get the serial number or UUID, but the other information like name, version, and vendor is accessible to all users.

Comment: You could potentially change the permissions with udev rules though, add a group membership for example and add condor to the group.

Comment: @MatthewIfe I don't think he needs to, though, because he didn't mention anything about needing serial numbers.  Just manufacturer and model (which are called sys_vendor and product_name here).

In any case, this information probably comes 12 years too late to be of use to the original poster.